# What keystrokes are required to navigate back from the bash shell to the editing windows?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, multi-term

I have configured the spacemacs "shell" layer and set it up with `multi-term` to use the `bash` shell. When I activate it with `SPC '` and enter the bash shell some of the keys like `Ctrl-w` used for navigating the windows are trapped by `bash`.

```
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     ;; Example of useful layers you may want to use right away.
     ;; Uncomment some layer names and press <SPC f e R> (Vim style) or
     ;; <M-m f e R> (Emacs style) to install them.
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     helm
     auto-completion
     emacs-lisp
     git
     markdown
     org
     syntax-checking
     elixir
     erlang
     ;; better-defaults
     (shell :variables
            shell-default-shell 'multi-term
            shell-default-height 30
            shell-default-position 'bottom)
     ;; spell-checking
     ;; version-control
     )

(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (setq multi-term-program "/bin/bash")
  )
```

Are there some pre-existing key combinations that can be used instead?

Comment: `eshell` is a pure elisp shell. It is definitely not `bash`, and it does not run in a terminal emulator. Can you please clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I have updated the question. I configured the shell to use `multi-term` and set `multi-term` to `bash`. It is related to a related question at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32680 and have seen your answer there.

Comment: I've made some further changes to the text in an attempt to clarify. Please note that `shell` is likely to be interpreted as referring to `M-x shell` which is a comint-based shell integration, entirely distinct from running a shell in a `term` buffer (or `ansi-term`, `multi-term`, etc). Furthermore, `shell-mode` is *unambiguously* a reference to `M-x shell`, so most definitely avoid writing that if it's not what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `multi-term` unbinds `'("C-z" "C-x" "C-c" "C-h" "C-y" "<ESC>")`. These defaults allow commands like `C-x o` (`other-window`) that you can use to move point to another window. If the default setting doesn't include some bindings you'd like to use you can adjust `term-bind-key-alist` and/or `term-unbind-key-alist` to the values you prefer.

Comment: To be totally frank I don't know what these terms mean. I have just started with emacs/spacmacs.

Comment: Type `M-x describe-variable RET term-bind-key-alist RET` for documentation and current value. See https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm for discussion and examples.

Comment: The result is `[No match]`

Comment: Make sure `multi-term`is loaded, e.g. with `(require 'multi-term)`.

Comment: `multi-term` is set to use `bash` and I have it already running when run `M-x describe-variable RET term-bind-key-alist RET`. Is there some other place where I should enter the `(require 'multi-term)?

Comment: If `term-bind-key-alist` isn't defined you almost certainly don't have `multi-term` loaded. You can run `M-x eval-expression RET (require 'multi-term) RET` to ensure it is loaded.

Comment: It turns out `C-x o` does the trick.