# What is the keybinding for toggling between editing the shell contents as a buffer and running commands in it?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, shell

What is the keybinding for toggling between editing the shell contents as buffer on one hand and running commands in it on the other? I have configured `multi-term` to run `bash` and the shell is switching to buffer editing mode via some keystrokes I am not sure off.

So far the `Esc` key appears to enter normal Emacs editing mode and `Ctrl-z` exits it, ie when in the shell? Are they the standard keys?

I am using Spacemacs in evil-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(n.b. I *assume* you're talking about a `term` buffer, and not about `shell-mode`).

I don't know about `evil` but the standard bindings are:

- <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> to change to `term-line-mode`
- <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd> to change to `term-char-mode`

In char mode most keys send their input to the terminal process.

In line mode you can edit the buffer as text.

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Term Mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: See also a tip for unifying the two commands under a single toggle, which I have found useful: http://joelmccracken.github.io/entries/switching-between-term-mode-and-line-mode-in-emacs-term/

Comment: I have done some reading and I think the keys you are describing may be overriden by Spacemacs. I will test Emacs to see if they are appropriate it. I have to learn Emacs anyway.